# Using React.js to show a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to write a very simple react program that displays a button to the user and when clicked, it calls an API and displays the results as a list.

I am at the point where I can press the button and debugging I see the data is pulled and manipulated to the way I need but it is not being displayed on the screen. Here is the work I have done so far;

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    users : []
  };
}

handleClick() {
  fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/user/")
  .then(results => {
    return results.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    let users = data.map((user) => {
      console.log("user - ", user.name);
      return (
        <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
      );
    })
    // this.setState({users: users});
    return (
      <ol>
        {users}
      </ol>
    );
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

render(){
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Get All Users</button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I'm proposing:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function getData(callback) {
  fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/user/")
    .then(results => {
      return results.json();
    })
    .then(callback);
}

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      data : null
    };
}

handleClick() {
  this.props.getData(data => this.setState({ data }));
}

_renderUsers() {
  return (
    <ol>
      { 
        this.state.data.map(user => <li key={ user.id }>{ user.name }</li>) 
      }
    </ol>
  );
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={ this.handleClick }>Get All Users</button>
        { this.state.data && this._renderUsers() }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Button getData={ getData }/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

- First I think the `fetch` should be outside of React component. React is only about rendering data not making ajax calls. In the code above `getData` is a external function passed as prop.
- The component has no async logic anymore and it renders what's in the state. Initially `data` is null and later is filled with the data from the API. The `setState` triggers the re-rendering.
- `handleClick` in your example is run without a context so inside you'll probably not be able to do `this.setState`. That's why in the constructor we do `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)`. We bound it the component's context.

Comment: Thanks Krasimir. Your proposed solution worked. And thanks for explaining why `this.setState` was null, this was really confusing me while I was trying to debug

Answer (score 1):

You can't return jsx asynchronously like that. I would recommend amending the final `then` to something like as follows:

```
.then(data => this.setState({ data }));
```

You can set the default `data` to be an empty array so you don't have to worry about mapping.

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  state = { data: [] };
}
```

Then, change the render to respond to `state`

```
render() {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(d => <li>{d}</li>)}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

To explain, here's the process:

- `onClick` makes an asynchronous call that loads data
- when the data is loaded, it updates state to be the new data.
- changing the state will cause a call to `render` using the new state.

Answer (score 0):

Your `handleClick` method is just an event handler, meaning it fires when you click the button, but it doesn't actually render anything. As such, returning a list here won't do anything.

Instead, update your state with the users and render those separately from the button. For example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    users : []
  };
}

handleClick() {
  fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/user/")
  .then(results => {
    return results.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    let users = data.map((user) => {
      console.log("user - ", user.name);
      return (
        <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
      );
    })
    this.setState({users: users});
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Get All Users</button>
        {this.state.users.length > 0 &&
          <ul>
            {this.state.users}
          </ul>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

handleClick() method should not return your result, as it does not do anything with it, you should update a state variable that in turn updates the render logic

short example below on how to update on click:

(you can run/edit this example via jsbin: http://jsbin.com/vumaqam/edit?html,js,output )

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {users:[]};
  }

  handleClick(){
    console.log("clikc");
    this.setState({users:["joe","smith"]});
  }


  getList(){
    // key must be unique, if user name is not unique must use other key
    return this.state.users.map((user)=>(<li key={user}>{user}</li>));
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>{this.handleClick()}}>Get All Users</button>
      <ul>{this.getList()}</ul>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(
  <Button />,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```